# Empty responseText in Phonegap running on android

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, responsetext

I have seen some other questions about it but nothing that solve my problem. I am using the code below to make a ajax request on phonegap 2.9.0. The cross domain permission is fixed. Running on my browser, the script is perfect. But when it comes to Android It runs all the code but the responseText get empty.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.open("GET", url, true); 
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
        if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) { 
                $("#app").html(request.status + request.responseText);
            }                 
        } 
    } 
    request.send();
```

So, as you can see in the code, the #app element receive the request.status value 200 but the responseText is empty on android device, but in the browser is works fine. It shows the data that I am looking for.
Anyone knows what is this?

Comment: Put alert inside the  request.onreadystatechange = function(){                         alert("I am here");
        if (request.readyState == 4) {

Comment: I didnt undertand why to use "alert"? I can even call this inside the second if statement, where I should handle the result of the request. It works. But the point is that responseText is empty here. :/ Any help?

Comment: Use alert or console for debug purpose. whether its getting inside the loop or not. If you not getting alert, then the problem with your url

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and it works fine as I said. The result of the <code>$("#app").html(request.status + request.responseText);</code> is only the "200", the request.status. It is the only thing that is shown. I have made a test inside it ( request.responsetText == "" ) and it returns true. But when I am in the browser it returns false, because it returns the text on the the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I made 2 changes: 1 changed the version of phonegap to 2.5.0 and called the file not as json, but as text and then use JSON.parse to make it be understandable. And then it works!